# JavaScript window.open() doesn't load window immediately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have below code. It tries to open a window on line 6. But it keeps loading (shows processing in title bar with blank content in the window). When I step through the code in the debugger and move on line 10 completing execution of line 9, the window finally loads, giving me error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null on line 9.

I don't get why `window.open()` does not complete loading web page immediately on `window.open()` and why it always complete loading when I pass through line 9.

```
var pageURL='url';
var w=500;
var h=500;
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, "_blank",'toolbar=no, location=no,directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
var windowStr = targetWin.document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var divMatch = windowStr.match(/someregex/);
console.log(divMatch[0]);
```

After reading suggestions online I put following after line 6, but same behavior!!!

```
targetWin.document.close();
```

What's going on here? I am debugging in Chrome.

Comment: will appreciate any comment before down vote...I know this may not be working code...but still people's experience can talk...and if one really needs a dummy code...then I have to prepare it and see if it gives same behavior. But then please ask that dummy code is absolutely needed before down voting.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you explain more? If it is something about CORS, then it should not load at all, not even after line 9 right?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't get why `window.open()` does not complete loading webpage immediately

This is because `window.open` is *asyncronous*. To get the contents of the window, you need to wait for it to be loaded.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When `window.open()` returns, the window always contains `about:blank`. The actual fetching of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the referenced resource are done asynchronously.

You could wait for the `load` event:

```
var targetWin = window.open (...);
targetWin.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Continue doing stuff here.
});
```

Alternately, you might wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Also, note that this can only be done if [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is respected.